# Over what distance will one coal power a Minecart with Furnace?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I use Minecarts, I hate having to use Powered Rails to move them. I would like to use a Minecart with Furnace to push my Minecarts, but I don't know how much fuel I'll need.

How far can a Minecart with Furnace go using one piece of coal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart_with_Furnace#Usage):

> Each piece of fuel powers a minecart with furnace for 3 minutes. Adding another piece of fuel at any time increases the total range by another 3 minutes. [...] Minecarts with furnaces **on a level track** will cover 204m per minute (about 3.4 m/s), or 612m per piece of coal. Pushing multiple minecarts may decrease the range slightly, depending on collisions. Minecarts with furnaces can also pull up to four other minecarts behind them if the carts are first shunted together against a wall and then the furnace minecart is made to change direction.

Comment: Could you convert 612m to blocks?  I'm not familiar with meters.

Comment: @RavenM 1 block = 1 metre.

Comment: How about up/down slopes?